# Migrate users from custom table to ASP.NET Membership tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-membership

I'm creating a new middle tier where all of our client calls will go through a WCF service.  We're using ASP.NET membership with the service in order to authenticate users.  The middle tier will be hitting an existing database in which we already have an InetUsers table containing usernames and passwords.

This is where it starts to get messy.  This new middle tier will be used by our web application, but not by our existing desktop application, which will - until we rewrite it at some point in the future - be using the old COM+ middle tier.  Administration of the users for the web application takes place in the desktop application.  In other words, users will be created and passwords set and changed from within the desktop application, which in turn hits the already existing InetUsers table.

Ideally, what will happen is when we deploy the new middle tier, we'll take all of the users from the InetUsers table and create records for them in aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership.  Then we'll set a trigger on the InetUsers table to keep aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership up-to-date.

There's a whole bunch of questions wrapped up in this, so I'll try and list them all out here:

- Is this the right approach?  Obviously having this data in two places isn't ideal, but bear in mind here that I'm not the final decision maker here and we're kinda stuck with some legacy stuff here, at least for now.  Still - maybe there's a better way.

  In the same vein - would we be better off coding our own membership provider rather than using the SqlMembershipProvider?  How difficult/easy is it to do so?

  If we use this approach, I plan on using the aspnet_Membership_XXXX stored procedures for the initial population of the tables as well as in the triggers.  Having done some research into this, it appears that if I want to call aspnet_Membership_CreateUser directly from SQL (ie in a trigger...) rather than using the API, I have to store clear text passwords since I can't get the salt and the hash right otherwise.  Is this true?

  Does any of this even make sense or am I going about this the wrong way to begin with?

Much appreciation for any help offered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have a database structure, I would write a custom membership provider and skip the existing membership structure.  That way you are using one database structure that the developers are already used to, whether for data access, reporting, or other purposes.  Create a class that inherits from MembershipProvider.  Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx or http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256/0/page/3.

You only need to implement the features you actually need.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that will be the best fit for us, so I'll look into getting that implemented.

Comment: thanks again, it's a much better solution for us using the custom provider I've coded.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't "difficult" to code your own membership provider.  If you're planning on living with the hybrid solution for a while, it would probably be cleaner to roll your own provider than maintain the data in two places.

Then, when you're ready to move to the new, standard, membership provider, it should just be a matter of transfering the users over once and re-pointing to the new provider for both the desktop and web interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @Kendrick - good advice.  I picked @Brian's answer because he linked articles about rolling my own membership provider, but the idea of migrating to the SqlMembershipProvider in the future is a good one and one that I'll keep in mind.